# Let $G$ be a group and $H, H'$ be subgroups of $G$ where $H$ is normal. Under which circumstances is $H \cap H'$ a normal subgroup of $H$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups, quotient-group

To be more specific, what kind of assumptions do I have to make for $H'$ to obtain this assertion? Which one are necessary and which one are sufficient?

For instance, we could say $H \subset H'$, but this case seems rather boring. Do you have some better ideas? Thank you!

Comment: What else do you expect? In order to be normal subgroup, it would need to be subgroup first. Once it is a subgroup, it automatically is normal since it is normal in a bigger group.

Comment: If $N$ is normal in $G$ and $K$ is a subgroup of $G$ then $N \cap K$ is a normal subgroup of $K$. You don't need any assumptions on $K$ for that to be true.

Comment: I just noticed that I made a huge mistake in the headline: $H'$ does not has to be necessarily normal!

Comment: In that case, I don't see what difference $H$ being normal in $G$ makes. Anyway, you'll find that with questions like this you only get what you seek in "trivial" cases.

Comment: Please include the full text of your query in the body of your message, not just in the title. In fact, the title should be suggestive, but should not be a full two sentences!

Comment: As people have pointed out above, a better idea than $H\subseteq H'$ is to require $H'$ be normal in $G$. Probably the best you can do aside from simply restating the goal as a condition, i.e. that $H'$ satisfies $H'\cap H$ is normal in $H$.